# Semantic UI segments floated property use

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to have a segment float to the left and to the right in this situation. I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how floats work. I have no idea why the right segment is behaving this way.

Left highlighted in blue and right highlighted in red for clarification.

[image]

Perhaps Segments aren't the solution here?

This is my layout component:

```
return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Navbar />
      <Segment floated={"left"} style={{
          height: "65vh",
          marginLeft: "1rem",
        }}
      >Left Floating Segment</Segment>

      <Segment style={{
          height: "80vh",
          margin: `0 auto`,
          width: "60vw",
          padding: `0 1.45rem`,
        }}>{children}</Segment>

      <Segment floated={"right"} style={{
          height: "65vh",
          marginRight: "1rem",
        }}>Right Floating Segment</Segment>

      <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that putting the segments in a container with `display: flex` was enough to get them to behave.

`<Container style={{display: 'flex'}}> </Container>`